# Android Messages does not recognise phone numbers in messages

Tags: sms

I have a Nexus 5X with Android 8 (Oreo) and [Android Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) v2.5.211

I can not call most numbers in messages by tapping them. After some research I found that is works for others, but not on my phone. What could be the cause?

Example:
Working (not my phone):
[image: Working (not my phone)]

Not working (my phone):
[image: Now working (my phone)]

The first screenshot is from Android 7.1.1

Comment: What about  numbers in international format? +38 xx xx xx xx xx

Comment: @esQmo_ I think that is recognised.

Comment: Did this happen after the update?

Comment: @esQmo_  I upgraded to Oreo recently and the Messages app is regularly updated (automatically). I'm not sure when the problem started though.

Comment: Should you try basic stuff such as clearing the caches (phone cache from the recovery and the app-android messages- cache from settings > applications)

Comment: @esQmo_ Did that, no change.